# What does this memtest result mean?

Tags: memtest

I have been having trouble with my macbook pro mid 2014 freezing. I couldn't find anything in any log and I've tried updating all software etc, and I still get freezing a few times a day, requiring a hard reboot. I've been running memtest to see if there is a problem with the RAM. Tests 1-12 seem to pass reliably, whereas it often freezes on test 13, hammertest. In the logs I generally get nothing when it freezes, but I did get the following one time:

```
2017-10-23 12:05:06 - All memory ranges successfully locked
2017-10-23 12:05:18 - RunHammerTest - Running hammer test on 4 CPUs (128MB each) [0x100000 - 0x20100000]
2017-10-23 12:05:44 - RunHammerTest - Running hammer test on 4 CPUs (128MB each) [0x20100000 - 0x40100000]
2017-10-23 12:05:44 - [MEM WARNING] Test: 13, CPU: 0, Address: 0, Expected: C600CA29, Actual: 43425355
2017-10-23 12:05:44 - [MEM WARNING] Test: 13, CPU: 0, Address: 4, Expected: 42522448, Actual: 00000256
2017-10-23 12:05:44 - [MEM WARNING] Test: 13, CPU: 0, Address: 8, Expected: 77AB51EB, Actual: 00000000
2017-10-23 12:05:44 - [MEM WARNING] Test: 13, CPU: 0, Address: C, Expected: 10A81502, Actual: 00060000
```

Can someone tell me what this means?

Does it suggest there is a problem with the memory or not?

Why is it only a warning?

I read that the hammer test quite often fails on machines that are otherwise reliable?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry about. RowHammer is a well-known vulnerability in RAM modules, where fast data updates can lead to data corruption.

According to their help page, you can

- Do nothing (not likely to affect you in a daily use scenario)
- Replace the RAM modules (if you have the budget, and the time to search for RowHammer-safe modules)
- Use RAM modules with error-checking capabilities (eg. ECC) (that is usually  for servers, not for home use)